# Trying to duplicate headers in a new row, everytime the date column changes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vba

I need to find the best way to duplicate the headers row into a new header everytime the "Game date" column changes. For this week there are 2 games on Saturday and the rest of them are for Sunday, in this case I'll need the headers to duplicate just once. But if there are other dates, it must duplicate accordingly.

The dataframe was built with Python pandas, but it needs to be opened in excel, therefore I could change the code in Python or I can try to add some VBA to the excel sheet.

```
Output:

Game Date   Game Time   Visit   Home    Roof
Saturday, January 7, 2023   1/7/2023 13:30  Kansas City Las Vegas   Fixed
Saturday, January 7, 2023   1/7/2023 17:15  Tennessee   Jacksonville    Open
Sunday, January 8, 2023 1/8/2023 9:00   Tampa Bay   Atlanta Retractable
Sunday, January 8, 2023 1/8/2023 9:00   New England Buffalo Open
Sunday, January 8, 2023 1/8/2023 9:00   Minnesota   Chicago Open
Sunday, January 8, 2023 1/8/2023 9:00   Baltimore   Cincinnati  Open
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Desired output:

```
Game Date   Game Time   Visit   Home    Roof
Saturday, January 7, 2023   1/7/2023 13:30  Kansas City Las Vegas   Fixed
Saturday, January 7, 2023   1/7/2023 17:15  Tennessee   Jacksonville    Open
Game Date   Game Time   Visit   Home    Roof
Sunday, January 8, 2023 1/8/2023 9:00   Tampa Bay   Atlanta Retractable
Sunday, January 8, 2023 1/8/2023 9:00   New England Buffalo Open
Sunday, January 8, 2023 1/8/2023 9:00   Minnesota   Chicago Open
Sunday, January 8, 2023 1/8/2023 9:00   Baltimore   Cincinnati  Open
Sunday, January 8, 2023 1/8/2023 9:00   Los Angeles Denver  Open
Sunday, January 8, 2023 1/8/2023 9:00   Detroit Green Bay   Open
```

[image: This what I need]

This is what I have so far :

```
Sub InsertHeaderRow()

    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    If cell.Value <> cell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
    
    Rows(1).Copy
    cell.Offset(1, 0).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    
    End If
    
    Next cell

End Sub
```

This creates a new row with the correct info, but it places the new row in the wrong place.

Comment: Please provide some code showing that you have made an effort to solve the problem. And also posting images as data invites downvotes. Because they make your problem hard to recreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Duplicate Header Row

[image]

```vb
Sub DuplicateHeaderRow()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' table
    
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = rg.Rows(1) ' header
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' data
    
    Dim durg As Range, dCell As Range, c As Long, IsNotFirst As Boolean
    
    For Each dCell In drg.Columns(1).Cells
        If IsNotFirst Then
            If dCell.Value <> dCell.Offset(-1).Value Then
                If durg Is Nothing Then
                    Set durg = dCell
                Else
                    c = (c + 1) Mod 2
                    Set durg = Union(durg, dCell.Offset(, c))
                End If
            End If
        Else
            IsNotFirst = True
        End If
    Next dCell
    
    If Not durg Is Nothing Then
        durg.EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
        hrg.Copy Intersect(durg.EntireRow.Offset(-1), drg)
    End If
 
End Sub
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly !! Thank you very much, I only had to change the Sheet name and the correct column.

Answer (score 1):

now that you showed your code attempt, it's easier to help you

here's the revision of your code with changes commented

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertHeaderRow()

    Dim iRow As Long
     
    For iRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1 ' iterate backwards from column A last row to the third one (the 2nd one already has its headers in first row)
    
        If Cells(iRow, 1).Value <> Cells(iRow - 1, 1).Value Then ' compare column A current row cell content to the cell right above
        
            Rows(1).Copy
            Cells(iRow, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```

you can improve the code above by first collecting all the rows that need a new headers row and then inserting the new headers in one go

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertHeaderRow2()

    Dim headersRng As Range
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1 ' iterate backwards from column A last row to the third one (the 2nd one already has its headers in firsst row)
    
        If Cells(iRow, 1).Value <> Cells(iRow - 1, 1).Value Then ' compare column A current row cell content to the cell right above
            ' update the "collection" of the cells that will need an inserted header
            If headersRng Is Nothing Then
                Set headersRng = Cells(iRow, 1)
            Else
                Set headersRng = Union(headersRng, Cells(iRow, 1))
            End If
        End If
    
    Next
        If Not headersRng Is Nothing Then ' if any cell need an inserted header
            headersRng.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown ' make room for headers
            Rows(1).Copy headersRng.Offset(-1) ' copy the header to the proper position
        End If
End Sub
```

finally, for the records, here follows the first code I posted

if you don't mind using a helper column just a the right of your data, try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertHeaders()

    With Worksheets("Your Worksheet actual name")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            If .Rows.Count > 3 Then
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 2, 1).Offset(2, .Columns.Count)
                    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-5]<>R[-1]C[-5],1,"""")"
                    .Value = .Value
                End With
                
                    With .Resize(, .Columns.Count + 1)
                        .AutoFilter field:=.Columns.Count, Criteria1:="1"
                        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
                            If Application.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
                                Dim headersRng As Range
                                    Set headersRng = .Resize(1).Offset(-1)
                                        With .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible)
                                            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
                                            Dim iArea As Long
                                                For iArea = .Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
                                                    headersRng.Copy
                                                    .Areas(iArea).Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                                                Next
                                        End With
                            End If
                        End With
                    End With
                    
                    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 2, 1).Offset(2, .Columns.Count).ClearContents
            End If
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I put the spreadsheet's name (Book1) I get a Run-Time error'9' - Subscript out of range, and when I use the sheet's name (Sheet2) nothing happens. I use excel 2021

Comment: as written in the code you have to put your worksheet actual name within those quotation marks

Comment: BTW, you made no efforts in searching a solution
I'm offering you a tested working solution: you can now make your trial and error job (which is very, very helpful to really learn) to get through it.

Comment: You have no idea how hard I've tried to solve this, unfortunately I have very little experience with VBA, that's why I dared to post my question here

Comment: Dare to post your hard tries, then: They will give you more chance to get help and possible helpers more info about your question

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and assistance, your coding is very elegant, I couldn't make it work because I was selecting the wrong column, I needed to use VBA for this project, but I'm new to this language.